# Java iterators in Scala

Tags: java, scala

I have some java code I am trying to convert to scala:

```
package hello;

class HelloWorldApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            public SortedMap<Long, Long> toDates = new TreeMap<>();

            Iterator<Long> iterLong = toDates.keySet().iterator();
            while( iterLong.hasNext() )
            {
                System.out.println("TEST");
            }

    }
}
```

I used a converter to get this:

```
package hello

//remove if not needed
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

object HelloWorldApp {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val toDates: SortedMap[Long, Long] = new TreeMap[Long, Long]()
    val iterLong: Iterator[Long] = toDates.keySet.iterator()
    while (iterLong.hasNext) println("TEST")
  }

}
```

The problem is the iterator() call really is not liked in scala (which I am executing through spark)

```
<console>:190: error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.util.Iterator[Long]
 required: scala.collection.Iterator[Long]
                         val iterLong: Iterator[Long] = toDates.keySet.iterator()
```

I understand what he error is saying basically.  Though, I am not sure how to force the type of scala.collection on the keySet.iterator() call.

I did do this:

```
    val iterLong: scala.collection.Iterator[Long] = toDates.keySet.iterator()
```

To no avail  What else can I add to have that iterator come back and work correclty in the loop?

Comment: `toDates.keys.toIterator`

Comment: Recommended way is to import `JavaConverters._` and call `.asScala` when needed. See [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/conversions-between-java-and-scala-collections.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either convert from Java to Scala, or you can just work with the Java one directly.

### Converting

Add this import

```scala
import collection.JavaConverters._
```

and then use the new `asJava`/`asScala` methods to convert collections:

```scala
val iterLong: Iterator[Long] = (...).toScala
```

### Directly Using Java Types

When doing interop with java collections, it’s common to do

```scala
import java.{ util => ju }
```

So that Java collection types can be accesed via `ju.???` without fear of naming conflicts. With the above import in scope, write

```scala
val iterLong: ju.Iterator[Long] = ... // or let type inference do it for you
```

and use the Java API